# springboot package javax.persistence does not exist

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am following this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest

At the first step when I added class Employee by copying from the tutorial, it says `package javax.persistence does not exist`

I added dependencies given in the tutorial. I generated the initial project using spring initializr as described in the tutorial. My pom is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.trupt</groupId>
    <artifactId>cure</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cure</name>
    <description>cure</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[SDK selected in the IDE is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3mR9.png)

[Error messages in the IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqEyo.png)

Even in this simple step this is not working.

I have tried maven reimport, maven clean-install, invalidate caches and restart. None of these worked.

Should I add a dependency? Isn't spring data starter enough?

This is really hard.

Comment: Check your dependency tree. javax.persistence should be inside hibernate which is part of your starter-data-jpa dependency.  If not you can always add it manually (but this should not be needed):

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>

Also you could do a mvn clean install in the console first so maven will bring in the dependencies

Comment: you are using Spring Boot 3, you should do the import from the jakarta package instead of javax.
https://spring.io/blog/2022/05/24/preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [guide](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/) is written in a version of `spring-boot` < 3.x it mean that all `javax.` imports was moved to `jakarta.` And you are using  `<version>3.1.4</version>`
It mean that every imports also from guide will be

FROM

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
```

TO:

```
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
```

Also I suggest you to have a look at [preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0](https://spring.io/blog/2022/05/24/preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0)

Comment: What is date, i mean where to add it, can you give me here in comments an example ? I will update if it will be helpful for others to understand

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you are using has not been updated to the latest version of Spring Boot.  The latest version is 3.x and it requires imports like `jakarta.persistence` instead of `javax.persistence`.

In [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) select version 2.x of Spring Boot (currently 2.7.16) and everything will work without any other change.